# What is causing this next.js build error on the Vercel website?

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, pdf.js

I had a working next.js project where I upgraded next.js (12.0.7), Typescript (4.5.4) and pdfjs-dist (2.11.228), among other libraries. The project runs perfectly locally with `yarn dev` and builds perfectly locally with `yarn build`.

However, when I commit and push to Github. I get the following build output on the Vercel website:

```
Build error occurred
/vercel/path0/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:2358
    return this._jsActionsPromise ||= this._transport.getPageJSActions(this._pageIndex);
                                  ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/cjs/core.min.js:1:94)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) {
  type: 'SyntaxError'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Obviously this is a surprise, as that appears to be valid syntax.

My `tsconfig.json` contains the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I would appreciate any insite or direction. Thank you.

Comment: `||=` isn't valid syntax, is that in your code or in a in a library?

Comment: It’s in the pdf.js library located here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR assignment operator `||=` appears to have been added in ES2021. While it is supported by Node 16 which I am running locally, it is not supported by Node 14 which is the latest version I can configure at Vercel.

Until Vercel supports Node 15 or later, my solution is to revert to `pdf.js-dist 2.10.377`. As the pdf viewer is only used in the browser, I may also do a dynamic import.